# What is Babel's purpose in relation to Jest?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, babeljs, babel-jest

I have an API project where I've been successfully using Jest (`v26.x` because code coverage doesn't work with `v27.x` on Windows 10 for me) for unit testing. I've run into a situation where I'm trying to achieve sufficient code coverage on a module I'm testing, but not all functions in that module have been exported, so this is impeding my ability to achieve this.

I came across the NPM package `rewire`, which worked beautifully, as it allowed me to mock any functions I wanted. The only problem is that code coverage doesn't acknowledge the lines tested via `rewire` and the devs in the Jest GitHub said they don't plan to support this.

So then I saw a couple of  posts that people were successfully using `babel-plugin-rewire` to achieve the same thing as `rewire`, but that code coverage lines were successfully being acknowledged with this package. However, I cannot get this setup to work.

I think I understand the basics of Babel, as it pertains to browsers. It will take newer JS code and transpile/polyfill so that older JS code is generated that will work with older browsers of your choice.

But then I started seeing stuff about `babel-jest` and Babel being integrated into Jest and so on. Aside from the fact that I can't get `babel-plugin-rewire` to work, I feel like I don't even understand the basics of how Babel and Jest work together, or why Jest needs Babel.

What is the relationship between Babel and Jest?

Comment: Jest doesn't *require* Babel, but if you're writing code (including tests) that requires Babel transformations they must be run while testing, not just while building. Whether or not rewiring is the best approach or not is a separate discussion.

Comment: @DaveNewton Okay.  Thanks.

Comment: I would rewind right back to: why can't you get coverage of the module through the public API? You don't need rewiring, you need to delete unreachable code.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm also performing functional tests using Jest with SuperTest, but code coverage results aren't getting generated via that approach.  I can only get code coverage results with unit tests.  Is that what you were asking about?

Comment: You should certainly be able to get coverage from those integration tests, but there are other public interfaces. If a function isn't exported from a module, it's presumably called by other things that _are_, so test it _via those_.